# stored procedure with multiple resultset in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, stored-procedures, amfphp

I have been working on AMFPHP + codeigniter + flash and everything was working just fine but, when I created a stored procedure the problem started. I was able to call the stored procedure with multiple result sets from the AMF browser but whenever the function was called from the flash itself it raises the `Bad Version error`.

Below is the library {from CI forum} to traverse multiple result sets am using

```
class Mydb
{
   private $CI, $Data, $mysqli, $ResultSet;

   /**
   * The constructor
   */

   function __construct()
   {
     $this->CI =& get_instance();
     $this->Data = '';
     $this->ResultSet = array();
     $this->mysqli = $this->CI->db->conn_id;
   }

    public function GetMultiResults($SqlCommand)
    {
    /* execute multi query */
    if (mysqli_multi_query($this->mysqli, $SqlCommand)) {
        $i=0;
        do
        {

             if ($result = $this->mysqli->store_result()) 
             {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $this->Data[$i][] = $row;
                }
                mysqli_free_result($result);
             }
            $i++; 
        }
        while ($this->mysqli->next_result());
    }
    return $this->Data;

   }   
}
```

and calling it like this:

```
$this->load->library('mydb');
$this->mydb->GetMultiResults("CALL test()");
```

I have noticed that the library loading line raises the `Bad Version` error at flash end as if I comment out this line it works {works like no error is ther but SP doesn't execute}

Any Idea on how to fix this strange issue.

Comment: what version of CodeIgniter?  I'm using 3.1.4 6/2017

Answer (score 1):

Although CodeIgniter uses mysqli driver the next_result() method is not set in the DB_driver.
**[Here](https://phpsmith.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/callback_procedure-problem-with-mysql-in-codeigniter/)** and [**here**](http://forum.codeigniter.com/archive/index.php?thread-63754.html) you can find further details. The idea is:

1. define ***next_result()*** method in *system/database/DB_driver.php*:

   `function next_result()
   {
       if (is_object($this->conn_id))
       {
           return mysqli_next_result($this->conn_id);
       }
   }`

(be sure to push this up to your notes pile for the CI system core upgrade )

2. make sure you are using ***mysqli*** drive (application/config/database.php)
3. In your model after you call your stored procedure and BETWEEN each fetch of results use `$query_or_somethig-else->next_result();` (and use `$query_or_somethig-else->free_result();` in the final)

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on multiple query execution in store procedure in codeigniter
I created a library named SP.php. Here is the code also change in config to database =
mysqli

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class CI_SP {
        private $CI;

        function __construct() {
            $this->CI = & get_instance();
        }

        public function GetResults($SqlCommand) {
            $k = 0;
            $arr_results_sets = array();
            /* execute multi query */
            if (mysqli_multi_query($this->CI->db->conn_id, $SqlCommand)) {
                do {
                    $result = mysqli_store_result($this->CI->db->conn_id);
                    if ($result) {
                        $l = 0;
                        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            $arr_results_sets[$k][$l] = $row;                        
                            $l++;
                        }
                    }
                    $k++;
                } while (mysqli_next_result($this->CI->db->conn_id));

                return $arr_results_sets;
            }
        }

}
```

and the model code is

```
    $result = $this->sp->GetResults("call function(parameters);  
    $result1 = $this->sp->GetResults("call function(parameters));  

    print_r($result);        
    print_r($result1);          
    exit;   
    return $query->result_array();
```